# fgets stops reading the line on the character less (<) and not at the end of the line

Tags: php, fopen, fgets

```
function getRandLineFromFile($fileName)
{
    $hendel = fopen($fileName, 'r+');
    if (!$hendel)
        return '';
    $cLineCount = 0;
    $sLineOut = '';
    while (!feof($hendel)) {
        $cLineCount++;
        $sLine = fgets($hendel);

        if (rand(1, $cLineCount) == $cLineCount) {
            $sLineOut = $sLine;
        }
    }
    return $sLineOut;
}
```

If you try to read a line from a file that has a smaller character (<), then fgets trims the string before that character and not to the end of the line.

Example string in the file:

```
wordwordwordwordwordwordwordwordwordwordwordwordwordwordwordwordwordwordwordwordwordwordwordwordwordwordwordwordwordwordwordword<twotwotwotwotwotwotwotwotwotwotwotwotwotwotwotwotwotwotwotwotwotwotwotwotwotwotwotwotwotwotwotwotwotwotwotwotwotwotwotwotwotwotwotwotwotwotwotwotwotwotwotwotwotwotwotwotwotwo
```

result:

```
wordwordwordwordwordwordwordwordwordwordwordwordwordwordwordwordwordwordwordwordwordwordwordwordwordwordwordwordwordwordwordword
```

Comment: `<` is a statring symbol for html tags. So if you just output string like `<bla-bla` - browser considers it as html tag. You can view source html of your page and see there all your words.

Comment: Escape html entites - for example `htmlspecialchars`.

Comment: Thank you, you're right, figured out, everything works!